# How to change a SPAN's border color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Looking to highlight a Report button, by making it's border color red, however this doesn't seem to work. The code I've attempted to use is below.

```
document.getElementById("ReportBtn").style.border = "solid #FF0000";
```

I've even tried running it via the browser console, seems to just return null even though the page fully loaded.

```
<span onclick="return ReportReview()" class="btn_grey_grey btn_small_thin tooltip" id="ReportBtn" data-tooltip-content="Report this review for violating the Steam Terms of Service or Online Conduct Rules."></span>
```

Comment: Can't recreate problem... it should work:https://jsfiddle.net/htj1gkxL/

Comment: please show ReportReview() code

Comment: same as @nevermind, https://jsfiddle.net/3p5x25nr/

Comment: Also set the border width. `"1px solid #FF0000"` and see if that makes a difference. Maybe something else is setting it to 0px.

Comment: @nevermind Strange. It still doesn't work. https://3.milkgames.pw/AiBY3.png (look at the flag) Tomalak I tried and it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Remove return from your `onclick` event. It needs to be `<span onclick="ReportReview()">`

**html**

```
<span onclick="ReportReview()" class="btn_grey_grey btn_small_thin tooltip" id="ReportBtn" data-tooltip-content="Report this review for violating the Steam Terms of Service or Online Conduct Rules."></span>
```

**js**

```
function ReportReview() {
    document.getElementById("ReportBtn").style.border = "solid #FF0000";
}
```

See [js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rhqn7v7a/) which demonstrates what you want to do.

Perhaps you want to just change the color when the document has loaded. In this case the following should work. It basically means that when the page has loaded change the color of the border of the `span` element. You can only change the color of the span element if it has been created. This will ensure that it has already been created.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     document.getElementById("ReportBtn").style.border = "solid #FF0000";
});
```

Comment: I'm not looking into adding the border when I click the flag. Also it doesn't work.

Comment: when do you want to add the border? it isnt very clear from your question. From what you provided it looks like this is what you want. It works for sure. Did you check the jsfiddle? You need to figure out which element you want to add the red border to, and then put that in a function. Then you need to refer to the item that when clicked will change the color of the `span` element. Based on what I provided above you should be able to transfer this to what you want exactly

Comment: This is actually a Firefox Plugin, which basically uses javascript. I want the border to be added once the page is loaded.  And no it does not work. Once again I want to add it to a SPAN.

Comment: you should mention such details in your question, it'll make it easy for others to help you, and not build assumptions

Comment: @MilkGames check the last part of the answer as I think this is why it's not working for you

Answer (score 1):

Is it because your JavaScript is executing before your span is ready?

**Explanation edit**

Your JavaScript is fine

```
document.getElementById("ReportBtn").style.border = "solid #FF0000";
```

It will only work if it’s called after the span has been created.  It will fail if it runs higher up in your markup.

Comment: you should rephrase it as an answer and explain what you mean

Answer (score 0):

> use just onclick="ReportReview()"

it is the right way to call the function event. 
Return is not used in onclick event.

Comment: See my previous comments - 
 
This is actually a Firefox Plugin, which basically uses javascript. I want the border to be added once the page is loaded. And no it does not work. Once again I want to add it to a SPAN.